# Capturing Time Difference Between Statuses via DAX

Tags: datetime, time, powerbi, dax

[image: Slice of Data I'm trying to analyze]

I am working in PowerBI and I have a dataset showing candidate movement within hiring requisitions.  Via DAX, I would like to add columns that show the time difference between certain statuses.  E.g., the result would show "3" down the column for "New to Hire" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using three measures.  You will need to adjust `Table3` to reflect your actual table name.  I also assumed that there is a column that designates a unique ID for each employee.

New to Hire:

```
New to Hire :=
VAR CurID =
    MAX ( Table3[ID] )
VAR NewDate =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "New" )
    )
VAR HireDate =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "Hired" )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( NewDate, HireDate, DAY )
```

Offer to Accept:

```
Offer to Acccept :=
VAR CurID =
    MAX ( Table3[ID] )
VAR OfferDate =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "Offer Sent" )
    )
VAR AcceptDate =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "Offer Accepted" )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( OfferDate, AcceptDate, DAY )
```

Offer to Hire

```
Offer to Hire :=
VAR CurID =
    MAX ( Table3[ID] )
VAR OfferDate =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "Offer Sent" )
    )
VAR HireDate =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Table3[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table3 ), Table3[ID] = CurID && Table3[Status] = "Hired" )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( OfferDate, HireDate, DAY )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  You're right there's a column for a unique employee ID AND a column for unique requisition ID.  So an employee can appear on more than one requisition.  Will this method work by using the requisition ID?

Comment: @Shlammed yes, use the req ID column in place of ```Table3[ID]```